# Post request parameters in Java doesn't work

Tags: java, android, database, web-services

I've tried to handle POST requests from a java file to a PLAY server. On the server I print the parameters as `request().body().asText()`, which works if I use the curl command in the terminal. However, if i try to POST using a java file, it always prints `null`. I've tried multiple examples from this site, but it always prints `null`. (I do however get the correct return value back, so I do connect with the server).

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class javaa{
public static void main(String[] args){
     try{
          String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
          URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9000/createPerson");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          conn.setDoOutput(true);

          OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

          writer.write(urlParameters);
          writer.flush();

          String line;
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(line);
          } 
          reader.close();
          writer.close();
          conn.disconnect();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the method `POST` indeed by default it is a `GET`, it can be done by adding

```
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

You should also set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as next:

```
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You should also indicate to the server the size of your body as next:

```
byte[] requestBody = urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestBody.length);
```

So finally the code would look like this:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
byte[] requestBody = urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestBody.length);
try (OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream()) {
    out.write(requestBody);
    out.flush();
}
```

**Response Update**

According to your comments you should retry with:

```
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

instead of:

```
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still returns 'null'.

Comment: try to call writer.close(); after writer.flush()

Comment: The output is still null. I have just noticed maybe it was not clear that "null" output that is the problem is on the server side, which prints "request().body().asText()".

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a method for "write(byte[])".

Comment: sorry my bad, check again

Comment: Thank you for your help so far but it still returns null

Comment: "curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'Hello world!' http://localhost:9000/createPerson"

Comment: this is a `GET` with `Hello world!` as data which is not what you ask in your question

Comment: try this: curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d 'param1=a&param2=b&param3=c'

Comment: This command also does work, the server side print the parameters.

Comment: and this curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'param1=a&param2=b&param3=c'

Comment: so it returns null ?

Comment: it prints null with request().body().asText()

Comment: try to change the content type as explained in my answer update